React build script doesn't resolve node modules properly when running inside Docker
I'm trying to dockerize a react app (created with cra) with typescript (typescript was added manually later and not with cra)
This is my file structure:
<my app>
├── node_modules/
├── public/
├── src/
├── package.json
├── Dockerfile
├── .dockerignore
└── tsconfig.json

This is my Dockerfile:
FROM node:alpine3.18

WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN apk add --no-cache npm

COPY . /app

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]

EXPOSE 443

and this is the relevant part of my .dockerignore
node_modules/
build/

All works fine until the build step, it gives me this error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'redux-logger' in '/app/src/redux'

Which is correct, 'redux-logger' is not in '/app/src/redux', but I'm importing 'redux-logger' from node_modules and not from a local directory. The import statement is located in /src/redux/redux-store.ts:
import logger from 'redux-logger'

So react should be looking into node_modules and not in my src directory for the logger, I don't know why it behaves like that when running the build script from docker, when I build my app locally without docker it builds just fine.
Just in case this is my tsconfig.json content:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src", "src/custom.d.ts"]
}

Like I said this works just fine in local but docker gives me that error, what could I be missing here?

Make sure you add a .dockerignore file with node_modules/ in it. You don't want to copy in your host's node_modules directory

There's also no reason to install npm from apk. It's already present on all official Node.js images

I think you're misreading the error as well. The in '/app/src/redux' is referring to the module attempting to perform the import

Does this answer your question? Confusion with node_modules being ignored by .dockerignore

@Phil you are right, I didn't have node_modules on .dockerignore, however adding it didn't solve the issue, the culprit was the npm installation line in my Dockerfile, once I remove it the image was built just as expected, thank you for pointing me to the right direction!

My bad, I don't know why but the line with the npm run build command was commented and that was the reason the image was built without issues. The problem still persist.

The issue was that setting the env var NODE_ENV to production makes npm install to not install dev dependencies by default so I have to
npm install --include=dev

and I got rid of that particular error.

Why is redux-logger in your devDependencies?
